# using Qt destructors

Tags: c++, qt

I've just begun to study qt using qt-creator, I found some tutorials int which the author doesn't use d'tors at all? is it good practice? or it will be better to manage my objects destruction, thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a class doesn't declare a destructor, the compiler automatically gives it a definition equivalent to `{}`.  Often in Qt, this is good enough, even if the class contains pointers.  Whenever something derived from `QObject` is destroyed, Qt automatically deletes all its children (recursively) as well, as long as each child was passed a "parent" pointer.

If there's anything you think your class's destructor should do, definitely define it yourself.

One other quirk: If the destructor is the only virtual method defined in the class, providing your own non-inline definition can make generation of C++ magic data (vtables) easier on the linker on some systems.

After all the above is considered, whether allowing defaulted destructors is good practice is a matter of opinion.  (When I do allow a default destructor, copy constructor, default constructor, and/or assignment operator, I prefer to say that in comments in the public section of the class definition.)

Answer (score 0):

[Qt has Its own memory management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html),

Check this

[Memory management in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt)
http://silmor.de/33

BTW It is Qt not QT. Check This
http://ariya.blogspot.com/2009/01/qt-not-qt.html