# What is the purpose of passing a parent into a Qt class constructor?

Tags: qt, class, parent

What is the purpose of passing a parent into a constructor of a Qt class object?

Answer (score 4):

They ensure your heap-allocated QWidgets are taken care of nicely (`delete` called when it needs to be and such).

For a detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt/2491811#2491811) to a similar question.