# Parent passed to QPushButton's constructor

Tags: qt

I have been following this thread: [Memory management in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt/2491811#2491811)

```
QPushButton::QPushButton ( const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0 )
```

So, in an example I saw the following way of creating push button's object. My concern is the second parameter, "parent", a this pointer has been passed there, does it mean that this widget is its own parent? I know I am missing a point, please point it out.

```
button1 = new QPushButton("Button1", this);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful, `this` does not refer to the `QPushButton`.

This line of code :

```
button1 = new QPushButton("Button1", this);
```

is probably part of a `QWidget`-based class, and that's the one `this`refers to !

That means the `QWidget`-based class is the owner of the `QPushButton` it is displaying.

It also means that when the instance of the `QWidget`-based class is deleted, it will delete all its children elements, which means the `QPushButton` button1 will be deleted as well, automatically.

Comment: Very much thankful, `button1 = new QPushButton("Button1", this);` this line was in a my defined class, so this means that my class is the parent of the pushbutton in this case! Is my understanding correct?

Comment: So does that every widget accepts a qwidget pointer to set it to it's parent? I'm newbie

Answer (score -1):

Yes the parent you set here is the widget you're, you use parent parameter on controls of almost any GUI Framework to know where the control is.

See you