# Do I have to delete each (pointer) element of a QSet manually?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I have a class member:

```
QSet<QDialog*>* dialogs_;
```

Do I need to delete just dialogs_ or do I have to call delete on each element of it as well?

Comment: You have to provide some context. If your class only ever initializes `dialogs_` to `NULL` then no, you don't need to `delete` anything. Does it do something else? We don't know, you haven't told us.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
qDeleteAll(*dialogs_);
delete dialogs_
```

You can also do it without dereference:

```
qDeleteAll(dialogs_->begin(), dialogs->end());
delete dialogs_
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to somehow manually delete each `QDialog` in `dialogs_`, if it has any.

You can iterate through the `QSet` and `delete` them manually yourself. Because `QDialog` inherits from `QWidget`, another way is to simply `delete` the parent of all the dialogs if the parent is allocated on the free store as well, which will in turn `delete` them.

Note that there's no reason to allocate `QSet` on the free store, if that's what you're doing. You can save a `new`/`delete` operation by simply making it a direct member of your class.

```
QSet<QDialog*> dialogs_;
```

That's one less thing you have to worry about w.r.t. manual deletion.

Answer (score 0):

First iterate through your set, delete every object in it, and then delete the set object.

However, take a note that Qt has it's own memory management, and it might be ok just to delete the set, and leave the objects in it to be destructed by the Qt's mechanism.

Comment: I haven't used Qt for a while now, but I'm pretty sure that when you pass a ui element such as a `QDialog` to a parent object, that object becomes responsible for the memory management of the child ui element. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @ChrisParton It is, however if you delete the child, the qt system register that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt) and [this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)