# Closing application and delete all memory allocations

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I've written a Qt application where I call a lot of constructors:

```
Object o = new Object(blabla);
```

and I can't delete them until the user closes the program.

When the close button is clicked (or cmd-Q) I call this function:

```
qApp->quit();
```

Now does this function delete all previous allocated memory, or do I have to do it myself manually?
I've already looked in the documentation of the quit-function, but it doesn't mention it.

Comment: Are your objects all `QObject` instances? I ask because, in Qt, there is a special treatment of the destruction of class inheriting `QObject`.

Comment: In addition to what M.C. said... in general Qt has a very interesting/clever scheme for memory management.  Qt does a lot of memory management for you, particularly with the QObject parent pointers that are usually passed around as an argument in constructors.  read more about it here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt) or [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+memory+mangement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that function stops the main thread's event loop and returns control back to the main function

if your main is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
MyQObject obj();


return qApp.exec();
}
```

then RAII will delete obj which will propagate down to the children

if you need to cleanup other resources then you can use [`qAddPostRoutine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#qAddPostRoutine) to add a cleanup function, these will be called from the `qApp` destructor