# free dynamically allocated memory in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have noticed in QT 5 examples there is no delete call for new widgets allocated.

Does this mean in this example

```
using namespace std;

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabWidget>


//This is to be used in many files later until the code exits
short * AA = new short[1000000];


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyTabDialog w;
    w.show();


    delete[] AA;  
    return app.exec();

}
```

the delete call is not needed or its place is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory management in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt)

Comment: @MrEricSir That question's answers do not cover QObjects allocated in stack, which is the case with `w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this in your code snippet you should place delete after application event loop is finished:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyTabDialog w;
    w.show();


    int result = app.exec();
    delete[] AA;
    return result;
}
```

But why do you allocate AA from the heap? You can just define it as following:

```
short AA[1000000];
```

And in Qt examples the widgets commonly created dynamically, for example:

```
QWidget* myWidget = new QWidget(this);
```

In example above `this` is pointer to another QObject instance which is now the parent for `myWidget`. Now `myWidget` instance will be automatically destroyed on deleting of it's parent widget and that's why we don't need to call `delete` explicitly for this instance.

[Object trees and ownership reference here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Comment: I wanted on the heap because there will too many arrays needed to be global, their total size would make the stack too big

Comment: @Hatems, it seems when you allocate your variables statically (in my answer AA is defined as global static array) they for sure not stored on stack. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11698458/2266412

Comment: Thanks for the update. I agree global static variables are not in the stack. Good reminder

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all object variables are actually the object references, somewhat similar to C++ pointers. In C++, object can also be allocated on a stack (like `MyTabDialog w` in your code). It is not an unitialized pointer (`MyTabDialog *w` would be). It is initialized object that is created using its parameterless constructor and disposed using its destructor.

Because of that, there is no delete call for the variable `w` in your sample.

Same way it is possible to allocate and not delete arrays on the stack:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    short AA[1000000];
    // no delete is required to free AA, beware never to return pointer to it!
}
```

However the stack space may be more limited than the heap space, so huge structures are normally allocated on the heap.