# QT Destructor not being called

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem with qt console application, destructor of MyServer class is not being called. 
Here is my simplified code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "MyServer/myserver.h" 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv); 
    MyServer server;
    server.startServer();
    return a.exec();

}
```

myserver.h

```
class MyServer : public QTcpServer
    {
        Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyServer();
    QFile* file;
}
```

myserver.cpp

```
MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    file = new QFile("file.ini",this);

}


MyServer::~MyServer()
{
    QSettings settings(file->fileName(), QSettings::IniFormat, this);
    settings.beginGroup("testGroup");


    settings.setValue("testValue", "asdf");
        settings.endGroup();
}
```

Destructor should change the file.ini, but it doesnt.

Comment: How did you verify that `~MyServer()` is not called?

Comment: File editing procedure :)

Comment: It would not be called until `main()` returns.

Comment: Can you show that procedure or something similar that reproduces the problem? Try to make a [mcve], otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: You used `new` so you got screwed. Remove it and things will work properly. (it's not `~MyServer()` that didn't get called, it's `~QFile()`)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing at least one `#include` line. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I added includes, but they are irrelevant

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, by "remove it" I meant make `file` a `QFile` instead of a `QFile *`. That way the destructor will automatically be called at the right time.

Comment: I understood, but I used parent/cild mechanism, so file  will be destroyed. But the problem is with ~MyServer. Any reason, why it is not being called?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the destructor or printed something.

Comment: Reasons why the destructor wouldn't be called is because someone does `exit(0);` or the program crashes before it manages to get around to clean up. Another reason might be that Qt's parent/child mechanism just fails here.

Comment: Maybe there is a dependency in `QSettings` that `QCoreApplication` still has an event loop.

Comment: Another thinking! could this be related to QTcpServer destructor?

Comment: Who gets destroyed first, the parent or the child?  If it is the child, `file` will be destroyed before the parent (`MyServer`) destructor is called.  Therefore the writes to the file could not happen.

Comment: Reading the answers to this question on [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491811/447438] (Memory management in Qt?) should also help.

Comment: In the parent's ~QObject() the child is freed. This happens after ~MyServer() finishes.

Answer (score 2):

`MyServer::file` might be your problem. Are you opening that file for write access somewhere else in your code? Because `QSettings` will attempt to also open the same file, and your two concurrent accesses to the same file might be clobbering its contents.

If you don't need `MyServer::file` for anything, then get rid of it. `QSettings` does not need `QFile`. It only needs the filename.