# How dynamic memory allocation in child classes are handled in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm trying to understand how Qt is handling instantiating objects of its widgets which are using dynamic memory allocation in user defined classes.

In below you can see **main.cpp** and part of a user-defined class "**Foo**" which comes from Qt installation example projects.
As a newbie I know that whenever we allocated dynamic memory we have to see the `delete` also somewhere in the code.The question is where is such `delete` to delete the dynamic memory which is allocated in **Foo.cpp** in below line?
  `QChartView *mychart= new QChartView();`

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    Foo *myobj = new Foo();
    window.setCentralWidget(myobj);
    window.resize(900, 600);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
Foo::Foo(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QChartView *mychart= new QChartView();
...
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "handle" here. You wrote that code in Foo.cpp, so you the programmer did(handled) the dynamic allocation. Please explain more specifically what you are wondering about.

Comment: Whenever we allocate dynamic memory we have to make sure this memory is deleted somewhere in the code, by handle I meant this concept. But in example projects coming with Qt I don't see any `delete mychart` code. so I have assumed that Qt is handling such deletions, am I correct ?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with that QChartView - e.g. if you add it to another widget, that widget takes responsibility for it(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/memory-management-in-qt), but at least update your question with what you wrote in your comment, as that's what your question actually is about.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

1. Parent classes do not handle their children. Classes handle object they *own*. Any dynamically allocated objects *owned by* `Foo` should be cleaned up in `Foo::~Foo()`.
2. Likewise, dynamically allocated objects *owned by* `QMainWindow` are cleaned up in the destructor of `QMainWindow`. When you call `window.setCentralWidget(myobj)` you *pass ownership* of whatever is pointed to by `myobj` to `window`, so when `window` is destroyed, it deletes that object in its destructor. This in turns causes dynamically allocated objects *owned by* the object pointed-to by `myobj` to be cleaned up (see p.1)

Comment: Thanks! how the QmainWindow destructor ( which now have the ownership of `myobj` ) deletes `mychart` object in above code?
by how I mean what could be the code in the QMainWindow destructor ?

Comment: @Solarisan "which now have the ownership of myobj" Actually it has ownership of the object pointed to by `myobj`, not `myobj` itself. I corrected the answer. The code could be `delete this->centralWidget` for example.